# Connect Wall: Americana

Tags: history, seasonal, connect-wall

In honor of Flag Day here in the United States, I hope you're up for another connect wall! The set of sixteen words below can be partitioned into groups of four words that have something in common. And of course the commonalities have something in common, which is related to the title of the puzzle. I wish you luck!

BALL, BLUE, BRIG, CONNECT, DOC, ERR, FAB, FINAL, ORDER, PAR, REM, RIB, RUN, SLOTH, SPARE, TRY

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Connections

> Group 1
>  Words that precede **Four** = BALL, CONNECT, FAB, FINAL
>
>  Group 2
>  Words that are **Scores** = RUN, PAR, SPARE, TRY
>
>  Group 3
>  Words that be appended with **and** to form new words = BRIG, ERR, REM, RIB
>
>  Group 4
>  Words that appear in groups of **Seven** = BLUE (rainbow colours), DOC (seven dwarves), ORDER (taxonomic ranks), SLOTH (deadly sins)

Combining these gives

> "Four score and seven" = the first four words of Abraham Lincoln's [Gettysburg address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettysburg_Address), an important piece of Americana.

Comment: Crushed! Excellent job, hexomino!

Answer (score 3):

For starters:

> PAR, SPARE and TRY are sports terms; the fourth could be BALL, RUN or perhaps FINAL.